# Why does Datastore use Text type on property when saving 1 character

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following:

```
type Foo struct {
   BarX string
   BarY string
}
```

When setting *BarX* = **x** and *BarY* = **y**, the Datastore Viewer is showing *BarX* as being **Text** and *BarY* as being **String**. I would expect both to be **String** due to the length of the data.

I can't find any documentation on how to change this anywhere?

Comment: Show us how you save the entity. You know, a [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure there is no `datastore` annotations for the field? Does the entity implements PropertyLoadSaver?